# Declare order to show foreach output with PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I am currently trying to set up a custom sortable list. Without getting into too much detail as this would become a very large post, I would like to use the PHP foreach function to show the list.

I currently have

```
$video_id = $row['videos'];
  $res = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "",$video_id);
$exclude = explode(',', $res);
} ?>

....

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
<?php foreach ($video_list as $key => $item): ?>
<?php if(in_array($item['id'], $exclude)){ ?>
<li id="video-<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"><?php echo $item['id'], 
$item['title'] ?></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This generates a list of items from the database excluding items with an ID from an array which is also fetched from another table.

[image: Screenshot of database]

[image: Screenshot of ID's to be excluded.]

In this example, it will only show videos with the id 3,4 and 2. This is all working as expected. My issue is once I have reordered the items and refreshed the page they are loaded in numerical order. I need these to be load in the order specified (3,4 and 2 for this example).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Only tag the RDBMS relevant to your question!

Comment: Also, don't post images of your data, they aren't helpful to the volunteers that are trying to give you assistance. Please post your data as `text`.

Comment: The SQL tag could be seen as a language tag, I can understand the confusion.  Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ORDER BY FIELD (MySql), this lets you order by a field in a specific way.

> I need these to be load in the order specified (3,4 and 2 for this example).

Sounds like a good fit to me!

For example

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(3,4,2) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3,4,2)
```

This will select rows from table where the id is in the list and then order the results by id in the order they are place there, 3 then 4 then 2.

> excluding items with an ID

This might cause some issue, the Field order by assumes you know at least some of the values in the field.  Excluding implies that you know what you don't want but not necessarily what you do want, if that makes sense.

Maybe it's not an issue, I don't have enough information on your particular use case to determine that, so I am just mentioning it as a cautionary thing.

Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.